Crear decoraciones en laterales de página al imprimir con html y css
he estado dándole vuelta a este asunto y no consigo como hacerlo y, ya que dicen que dos cabezas piensan mejor que una, he llegado aquí con esta inquietud.
Estoy pasando este currículo hecho en Word a HTML y CSS, ya tengo todo montado, ¡pero no logro saber como puedo crear las decoraciones de página que tienen!

La idea es que el patrón verde se repita en cada página que se genere al imprimir, de antemano agradezco cualquier orientación que me puedan dar.

Debes poner lo que has intentado. Eso se hace con HTML, en tu caso como es para imprimir, yo recomendaría tablas, pero todo depende de ti

la solución que por ahora he implementado es la siguiente:
cree una imagen con el diseño que quería de fondo con GIMP, luego
mediante CSS la incorporé en el elemento principal de esta manera:
<style>
 @media print {
   main {
    background-image: url(./img/elPatron.webp);
    background-size: 100%;
    print-color-adjust: exact;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
   }
 }
</style>

he usado @media print, ya que solo quería que apareciera al imprimir el documento, se tuvo que agregar print-color-adjust para el forzado de la carga del fondo porque el navegador por defecto quito cualquier fondo que este
